# How to add an image and send it behind the text or add it as a background image?

Tags: vba, image, powerpoint

We are trying to create a ppt report based on Excel data.

I'd like the first slide to have a background image or just an image that is set behind the text.

```vb
Sub generatePptWithCharts()
  
    Dim coverImagePath As String
    imagePath = "C:\Users\user\Documents\vitalias-ppt-cover.png"
    
    'Powerpoint objects.
    Dim PowPntApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PowPntPrsnt As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PowPntSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    
    'Excel objects.
    Dim wbBook As Workbook
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ChartObj As ChartObject
    
    'Initialize the Excel objects.
    Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
    
    Set PowPntApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    
    PowPntApp.Visible = True
    PowPntApp.Activate
    
    Set PowPntPrsnt = PowPntApp.Presentations.Add
    
    Set PowPntSlide = PowPntPrsnt.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitle)
    
    PowPntSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = "Employee Information"
    PowPntSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange = "by Presenter"
    
    //This does not work properly
    PowPntSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(imagePath, msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0, 960, 540).ZOrder msoSendToBack
    
    PowPntPrsnt.SaveAs Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\EmployeeInformation " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss") & ".pptx"

    PowPntPrsnt.Close
    PowPntApp.Quit

End Sub
```

***The problem***

The code generates the ppt with an image sent behind the text, but I am getting the following error message:

> Methods 'close' of object '_Presentation' failed.

Also, the presentation does not close after saving it to the desktop.

I know it has to do with the way I am adding the image, because if I replace that line of code with the following code, it works properly (only the image is **not** behind the text):

```vb
PowPntSlide.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=imagePath, _
    LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
    SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=0, _
    Top:=0, _
    Width:=960, _
    Height:=540
```

***What have I tried***

```vb
Dim image As Shape

Set image = PowPntSlide.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=imagePath, _
        LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
        SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
        Left:=0, _
        Top:=0, _
        Width:=960, _
        Height:=540

image.ZOrder msoSendBehindText
```

That code gives me a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close. Three adjustments:

1. Excel has a Shape object. To use the PowerPoint Shape object instead of the Excel Shape object, you need to declare it as `PowerPoint.Shape`.
2. When you shift from using the `AddPicture` call to assigning it to an object with `Set image =`, you also need to add `( )` around the parameters.
3. You also want `.zorder msoSendToBack`. Per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.zorder): The `msoBringInFrontOfText` and `msoSendBehindText` constants should be used only in Microsoft Office Word.

This code works for me:

```
    Dim image As PowerPoint.Shape

    Set image = PowPntSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=imagePath, _
        LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
        SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
        Left:=0, _
        Top:=0, _
        Width:=960, _
        Height:=540)

    image.ZOrder msoSendToBack
```

Another alternative is to create the image as a true background image, more like a slide master. This is sometimes preferable because you can't select, delete, move, etc. the image directly. That code would replace all the above with:

```
    PowPntSlide.FollowMasterBackground = False  ' you must add this line
    With PowPntSlide.Background.Fill
        .UserPicture imagePath
        .Visible = True
    End With
```

Background code sample from: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/powerpoint-vba-select-image-and-turn-it-into/7ed490e5-5527-494b-b276-e8ace6e0bf0d?auth=1